# How to add a node to an existing XML document using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to make a script that adds a node to an XML document and every code that I can find doesn't work. I want to add a node that looks exactly like the machine node right under the machine node.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<machines>
  <machine>
    <vmname>NAME1</vmname>
    <network>NETWORK1</network>
    <hash>HASH1</hash>
  </machine>
</machines>
```

Comment: "every code that I can find doesn't work" - what code did you find, and how did it fail? :)

Comment: most recently: https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/08/19/mastering-everyday-xml-tasks-in-powershell... Under "add new data" section. kept throwing null value errors every time @Mathias R. Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone a node (a machine node), update its properties, and then append it to the original XML object (child of the machines node).

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<machines>
  <machine>
    <vmname>NAME1</vmname>
    <network>NETWORK1</network>
    <hash>HASH1</hash>
  </machine>
</machines>
'@

$newnode = $xml.machines.machine.clone()
$newnode.vmname = "NAME2"
$newnode.network = "NETWORK2"
$newnode.hash = "HASH2"

[void]$xml.machines.AppendChild($newnode)
$xml.Save("c:\NewXML.xml")
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I was able to derive what I needed from this.